# Cross.Thread violation

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I have a class with an event and a custom EventArgs. The meaningful code:

```
    public void OnTickReceived(TickReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        EventHandler<TickReceivedEventArgs> handler = TickReceived;
        if (handler != null)
            handler(this, e);
    }

    public event EventHandler<TickReceivedEventArgs> TickReceived = delegate { };
```

and consuming the class in a UI Windows Form subscribing the event like this

```
    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bool esito;
        t = new T3OpenStockReader();
        esito = t.Connect();
        textBox1.Text += "Connection: " + esito.ToString() + "\r\n";
        Application.DoEvents();
        if (esito)
        {
            esito = t.Subscribe("MI.EQCON.2552");
            textBox1.Text += "Subscription: " + esito.ToString() + "\r\n";
            Application.DoEvents();
        }
        if (esito)
        {
            t.Start();
            t.TickReceived += NewTick_Event;
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("Reading started...");
        }

    }

    private void NewTick_Event(object sender, TickReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text += e.tick.DT + " " + e.tick.Price + " " + e.tick.Volume + "\r\n"; 
    }
```

I receive an `InvalidOperationException` - cross.thread operation. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You shouldn't be, and I see no need for you to be, calling `DoEvents` in that button click handler.  You're opening yourself up to all sorts of bugs/problems unnecessarily.

Comment: Thank you, DoEvents is a remnant of last code refactoring.

Comment: Then just recognize that it's worth removing, as it's actively harmful, not just useless.

Answer (score 3):

> I receive InvalidOperationException - cross.thread operation. Where my error?

Presumably `T3OpenStockReader` raises events on its own thread - but you're trying to modify the UI in your event handler... which means you're doing it in the wrong thread. You should probably change your event handler to something like:

```
private void NewTick_Event(object sender, TickReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    Action action = () => textBox1.Text += e.tick.DT + " " + e.tick.Price 
                                           + " " + e.tick.Volume + "\r\n"; 
    textBox1.BeginInvoke(action);
}
```

I'd also suggest that you get rid of your `Application.DoEvents()` calls - they're a symptom of trying to do too much in the UI thread.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are trying to update a UI component on a non-UI thread i.e. `NewTick_Event`. You need to force the update back onto the UI thread e.g.

```
private void NewTick_Event(object sender, TickReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Invoke(new Action(() => textBox1.Text += e.tick.DT + " " + e.tick.Price + " " + e.tick.Volume + "\r\n")); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

NewTick_Event is invoked from another thread and the changes on controls must be invoked on the UI thread (for example by using BeginInvoke method)

```
private void NewTick_Event(object sender, TickReceivedEventArgs e)
{
   this.BeginInvoke( (Action) () =>
   {
      textBox1.Text += e.tick.DT + " " + e.tick.Price + " " + e.tick.Volume + "\r\n"; 
   });
}
```

Comment: Thank-you for all proposed solutions, but I'm looking for a solution that does not force me to know the client side (UI) that the class T3OpenStockReader works in multithreading. The class could be distributed to other Open Source programmers.

Comment: @StefanoGardini But that's the point, that class doesn't.  The event handler is in the Form's definition, not in your class's definition, so it is marshalling to its own UI thread.

Comment: The only option is to make T3OpenStockReader thread safe, for example by passing SynchronizationContext in constructor. Do you want some code?

Answer (score 0):

You get the violation because `textBox1` is owned by a different thread. You have to `invoke` the functionality on the other thread. Invoking is like asking to the thread (thats owns the `textBox1`): "Here thread, execute this when you have time...". so the thread that owns the `textBox1` will execute the functionality, instead of the thread that the event is raised from (or called, as events are call backs...).

I would go for this solution. Its a more generic approach than invoking on the textbox itself. And it doesn't matter what the event does, so you do not have to put all the functionality done by the event in a `(Action)` or `BeginInvoke`. You just simply call the event again, invoked, from the thread that owns the textbox.

Other answers in this topic do not check if invoke is required. I would say, that `InvokeRequired` boolean is there for a reason.

The `FormParentOfTextBox` in the example below is the instance of the form the textbox is put on. You could also use `textBox1` here, but again, it would become less generic approach.

```
    private void NewTick_Event(object sender, TickReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Thread safe approach, generally for every event.
        if (FormParentOfTextBox.InvokeRequired)
        {
            this.Invoke(NewTick_Event(sender, e));
            return;
        }
        textBox1.Text += e.tick.DT + " " + e.tick.Price + " " + e.tick.Volume + "\r\n";
    }
```